# How to have different link

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am new in JS > jQuery > select2 and ... english language!
My problem: I would like that the link in http://jsfiddle.net/JfWtJ/1/ is dynamic.

So, in first time, I test :

```
function format(state) {
    return state.text + "<a class='info' target='_blank' href='http://obs43/test.php?param="+state.id+"'  >link</a>";
}
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/) but it's not ok.

In second time, I test http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/1/ with:

```
$("#select").on('open', function() { 
    $('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function() { 
        $('#select').on('change', function() { 
            window.open("http://obs43/test.php?param=" + $("#select").val());
        });
    }); 
});
```

It's ok for the first select, but at the second select, there are two "window.open", at the third select, there are three  "window.open", etc.

Why? How do I do this correctly?

> I specify that I want that "window.open..." start with **ONLY** to click on "link" and not with "$('#select').on('change'..."

I use the second write because

```
$("#select").on('open', function() { 
$('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function() { 
     window.open("http://obs43/test.php?param=" + $("#select").val()); 
}); "
```

seem ok but if you see precisely, you remark that $("#select").val() is the precendly item, and not $("#select").val() of the choice in the list. And this last princip is correct in the full list but it's not ok when you use the list after a first search...

Comment: Do you want all links to open in the same window rather than a new window for each link.

Comment: A new window for each link.

Comment: The code that binds the event should only run once. In this case, it is enough to bind only to `change` event. Instead you are binding to `open` a handler that binds to `mouseup` a hander that binds the `change` event! This will geometrically increase the number of times the `change` handler is fired :)

Comment: I want that "window.open..." start with ONLY to click on "link" and not with "$('#select').on('change'..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this js it will fix your problem

```
 function format(state) {
// if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
return state.text + "<i class='info' id='"+state.id+"'>link</i>"+state.id;
//return state.text + "<a class='info' target='_blank' href='http://obs43/test.php?param="+state.id+"  >link</a>";
}

$("#select").select2({
formatResult: format,
escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});

   $("#select").on('open', function() { 
$('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function(event) { 
  //  alert(event.target.id);
     window.open("http://obs43/test.php?param=" +event.target.id);
}); 
});
```

Add this function

```
$("#select").on('open', function() { 
$('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function(event) { 
  //  alert(event.target.id);
     window.open("http://obs43/test.php?param=" +event.target.id);
}); 
});
```

Comment: No, it's not OK. Do you test ?

Comment: tell me what is not ok here?

Comment: I want that "window.open..." start with ONLY to click on "link" and not with "$('#select').on('change'..."

Comment: Your solution is my first test, but if you see precisely, you remark that $("#select").val() is the precendly item, and not $("#select").val() of the choice in the list. And the princip is correct in the full list but it's not ok when you use the list after a first search...

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/14/ I also update the answer please check and let me know.

Comment: It's better. It's good when we use the list, but the link is not ok when we begin (or/and use) a search with search box of select2.

Comment: I am not getting the reason of this error right now but if you check the example you gave in your example (http://jsfiddle.net/JfWtJ/1/) it also have the same problem.

Comment: "it also have the same problem":Yes, but it's not logical!

Comment: ok the solution is here http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/15/ . It will be helpful if you like my other questions/answer Really need some reputation point. thank you

Comment: OK! Perfect! "...upvote and accept it as answer..." Do you see my upvote ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have events being bound within other event callbacks.
For example in your code, on every "mouseup" on '.select2-results i' a new 'change' event handler gets attached to '#select' because you are attaching the event in the callback of the mouseup event. In simpler terms, what your code is doing - "when I mouseup on this link attach an event to #select". Hence multiple events get attached. Hence multiple windows get opened up.

All you would need is one single event which would look like this

```
$('#select').on('change', function() { 
    window.open("http://obs43/test.php?param=" + $("#select").val(), "linkWindow");
});
```

If you want to open all the links in the same new tab/window then in window.open pass the second optional "name" argument. Setting a name for your window makes sure that the new link would open in the window with that name "linkWindow", instead of opening another window. If a window with that name does not exist then a new window (with that name) opens up.

Here is the complete fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/3/

Comment: I want that "window.open..." start with ONLY to click on "link" and not with "$('#select').on('change'..." –