# How to have differents links with two select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

After this question : [How to have different link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930899/how-to-have-different-link) ,  I can't have the same use when there are two select2 on the page.
See http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/26/ :

```
function format(state) {
return state.text + "  ( " + state.id + " ) <i class='info' id='" + state.id + "'>link</i>";
 }

//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     #select0
$("#select0").select2({
//  formatResult: format
});

$("#select0").on('select2-selecting', function (e) {
alert("ok " + e.val);
 });

  //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     #select1
  $("#select1").select2({
  formatResult: format
});

// When selecting without using search box (no problem)
$("#select1").on('select2-selecting', function (e) {
alert("okkk " + e.val);
});

// link directly, without use search box of #select1 (no problem)
$("#select1").on('select2-open', function () {
$('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function (e) {
    alert("link 1 " + e.target.id+ " >>>OK");
  });
});

// link after a search with search box of #select1. Problem : it's not ok when there are two select2 on the page
$(".select2-input").change(function () { //change or focus
if ($(".select2-input").val() != '') $('.select2-results i').on('mouseup', function (e)      {
      alert("link 2 " + e.target.id+ " >>>OK");
  //  window.open("http://obs43.fr/carte6-04.php?ci=" + e.target.id);
});
});
```

1/ When I comment "#select0", the use of #select1 is ok: no problem.

2/ But with #select0, link of #select1 **after a search with search box of #select1** is not ok.

How do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Igor give me the solution:

> if ($(".select2-input") this selector is not specific enough. add a 
>   class to your select element which will then be copied to the select 
>   container, then change your selectors to include that.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/29/

```
 $(".second .select2-input").change(function () { //change or focus
 if ($(".second .select2-input").val() != '') $('.select2-results i').on('mouseup',    function (e) {
      alert("link 2 " + e.target.id+ " >>>OK");
});
```

But, there is a new question:
When I am in the search box of #select1, I have not the underline of the same letters in the list. I understand that function format() is the reason of this problem, but I don't know how get back this "function underline"?
CM